# akka actors Toolkit - context.actorOf vs system.actorOf

Tags: java, akka, actor

Could you please explain to me what is the difference between

> context.actorOf

and

> system.actorOf

?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Answer to this can be easily found in the Akka documentation:

> An actor system is typically started by creating actors beneath the
>   guardian actor using the ActorSystem.actorOf method and then using
>   ActorContext.actorOf from within the created actors to spawn the actor
>   tree.

- Actors spawned with `System.actorOf` will be children of the guardian actor.
- Actors spawned with `context.actorOf` will be children of the context itself - i.e. the actor which invokes the method.

As a more general suggestion, make sure you thoroughly explore Akka docs when in search of similar answers.